# iOS Coredata: Where to set up and load the database?

Tags: ios, core-data

I've followed the Stanford course and have now in all view controllers I use basically these setup functions:

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MainCategory"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES]];
    [self.budgetDatabase.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                       managedObjectContext:self.budgetDatabase.managedObjectContext
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                  cacheName:nil];
}

-(void)useDocument
{
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:[self.budgetDatabase.fileURL path]]){
        [self.budgetDatabase saveToURL:self.budgetDatabase.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            [self setupFetchedResultsController];
        }];
    } else if (self.budgetDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed){
        [self.budgetDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
            [self setupFetchedResultsController];
        }];
    } else if (self.budgetDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal){
        [self setupFetchedResultsController];
    }
}

-(void)setBudgetDatabase:(UIManagedDocument *)budgetDatabase
{
    if(_budgetDatabase != budgetDatabase){
        _budgetDatabase = budgetDatabase;
        [self useDocument];
    }
}
```

I've seen now several example projects where they initialize the whole coredata stuff in appdelegate.m (which I've hardly used so far I must admit) and wondered if my approach learned in the Standford course is correct? Or if I misunderstood? Should I make this setup in app delegate? Do you know a tutorial explaining this? I haven't found something explaining this for bigger applications...

Comment: the generic rule is, setup and load it _before_ you want to use it, and _save_ it when the changes should be committed. those could be different places in the code, it depends on when the data is supposed to be available for the _controller_ layer.

Comment: Well the `fetchedResultController` related code should go in your `UITableViewController` since it is paired with a UITableView.

Comment: And the useDocument and setBudgetDatabase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **rmonjo** suggested the stuff related to the `NSFetchedResultsController` should stay in a controller class. For example it could stay in a specific `UIViewController` class, a `UITableViewController` class or in a class from which other other classes can extend from (i.e. a base `UIViewController` class).

Concerning the code related to setup and load, I usually leave that code in the app delegate or I create a specific singleton class (that simply extends from `NSObject`) that can be accessed anywhere.

You can see an useful approach at [NSScreencast Core Data Basics](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/11-core-data-basics). Obviously that approach can be customized based on your needs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx alot, so basically I can just use the code generated for appdelegate when I create a project in XCode with CoreData checked Yes correct?

Comment: @MichiZH Yes. The code could be mantained in the app delegate or moved in a specific class. This choice is based on personal preferences. For me, second option is the preferred one.